# Send object from an UITableView to another UITableView without global array

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift4

I need some help please to pass data from a TableView to another one without to use a global array.
When I press a button I want to send a product from an UITableView (ProductsTableView) to another UITableView (CartTableView) but the problem is that I don't have a segue between this 2 tables.
How can I send the selected product from my first VC where I have the ProductsTableView to the second VC where is my CartTableView ?

Here is my code:

```
 // First VC
 class ProductsViewController: UIViewController{

 @IBOutlet weak var productsTableView: UITableView!

        // Function to add the product into the cart
            @IBAction func addProductToCartButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

                // Start animation region
                let buttonPosition : CGPoint = sender.convert(sender.bounds.origin, to: self.productsTableView)
                let indexPath = self.productsTableView.indexPathForRow(at: buttonPosition)!
                let cell = productsTableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! ProductTableViewCell
                let imageViewPosition : CGPoint = cell.productImageView.convert(cell.productImageView.bounds.origin, to: self.view)
                let imgViewTemp = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: imageViewPosition.x, y: imageViewPosition.y, width: cell.productImageView.frame.size.width, height: cell.productImageView.frame.size.height))
                imgViewTemp.image = cell.productImageView.image
                animationProduct(tempView: imgViewTemp)
                // End animation region
                // Start appending product to cart
                // TODO: add the logic for append here
                // End appending product to cart
                showAlertWith(title: "Added", message: "Product added with success.")
            }

       // "Product" is my entity from Core Data     
      func appendProductToCartList(product: Product){ 
      }

    // Function to send details about a product from this VC to another VC
        override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

          if let selectedIndexPath = productsTableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let cartVC: CartViewController = segue.destination as! CartViewController
                cartVC.cartProductsArray = [productsArray[selectedIndexPath.row]]
            }
       }
 }
 // Second VC
 class CartViewController: UIViewController {
      @IBOutlet weak var cartTableView: UITableView!
      var cartProductsArray = [Product]()
 }
```

Here is a GIF with my interface:

[image]

Thank you !

Comment: You can use NSNotificationCenter.

Comment: You can use delegate and protocols.

Comment: How can I use the delegate and protocol in my case ? Is hard to implement ?

Comment: You have the tabbar controller. you can access the cart view controller and append your product dictionary to its array.

Comment: @Ajaysaini how can be appended that product to the cartArray ? Because I don't know how to take the selected product.

Comment: you have populated your tableView with a array. so take out the dictionary on the indexPath in your method addProductToCartButton(_ sender: UIButton)

Comment: What is the data source(API, CoreData etc) for  `ProductsViewController`? What will happen if user directly goes to `Cart` screen without adding any data? If user quits the app then what will happen to the added products?

Comment: DataSource is CoreData and if the user go directly to Cart then the cart will be empty. Is not a requirement to have the saved products in the cart when you relaunch the app.

Comment: Ok, so you can query coredata to get the added products. Did you try that?

Comment: Here is my source code if is helping: https://bitbucket.org/florentin89/shoppingland/src/master/

Comment: No problems. You can watch one or two videos on YouTube and it will be enough to get started with CoreData and fixing the issue you have. You will need these products at many places in future so adopting the right approach from start will save a lot of effort.